# Visual Studio Code Replace in Files goes back to the start every time

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, find

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** on Windows PC.

I've noticed very strange behaviour in very basic search functionality.

When I found a string and Hit the **Replace** button, I expect the cursor to jump to the next hit. However, the cursor goes back to the first hit.

So every time I have to manually scroll down, going back to where I was making changes.

This doesn't make any sense. Yet, I don't find other people complaining. I wonder if I somehow messed up the configuration of VS code and caused this problem by myself.

Any thoughts?

Visual Studio Code

- Version: 1.77.1 (system setup)
- Commit:b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21
- Date: 2023-04-04T23:21:11.906Z
- Electron: 19.1.11
- Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
- Node.js: 16.14.2
- V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
- Sandboxed: Yes

Comment: can you tell us more specifically what you observe when you say "close to the first one"? Is the behaviour consistent in which hit it jumps to? Or does it change inconsistently with the exact same setup?

Comment: I thought I've seen other behaviours, but now I test it again, it's jumping back to the first one. I corrected my question above.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you are doing. There is more than one way to do find and replace in VSCode. It may indeed be some config setting or interference from some extension (because it doesn't sound at all like any behavior I have experienced).

Comment: "_I wonder if I somehow messed up the configuration of VS code and caused this problem by myself._" well... test that hypothesis: delete the contents of your user settings.json file (make a backup first). Then see if anything changes with respect to the problem. Try also a VS Code restart too.

Comment: @topsail, I meant Edit > Replace. It's by far the simplest way, right?

Comment: It's by far the simplest way? I dunno. But I cannot reproduce your described behavior when I try this with Edit > Replace.

Comment: I don't expect you can reproduce it. That would be a defect by design. Do you mean there is a simpler way to do Find and Replace? Using the shortcut key doesn't count because it is the same. I'd love to know another way, so I don't have to fix the issue.

Comment: By saying I couldn't reproduce I just mean what you say happens to you doesn't happen to me. Dunno if that is a defect or a design - it just means your vscode is not working the same as my vscode. I use Vim in VSCode so I have Vim find/replace and that is usually what I do. There are two dialogs for find/replace (ctrl+shift+h and ctrl+h) More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331181/how-to-find-replace-in-files-using-keyboard-in-vscode A lot depends on context, though. I might use vim, ctrl+H, ctrl+Shift+H, symbol refactor, regex or no regex, multiline, or simple typing - depends!

Comment: Try running the command `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` and report the output into your question.  That could help to see what command(s) are actually be called.